# Open SharePoint Online Site in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, office365

I'm developing a small site with SharePoint Online and Office 365. For this I'm using the approval template which is in SP 2010 template.When I try to open my site with SPD 2010 it's not working. It gives error as :

***microsoft sharepoint designer cannot be used to edit websites on servers different from Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010. To edit these sites, you need to use the same version of SharePoint Designer which matches the version of Microsoft SharePoint Server***

Of course I can open it with SPD 2013, but there isn't any possibility to use the http-action (because it's in 2010 template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SPD 2013 template to use HTTP action as it is available there only.

Please let me know if it helped or not

Thanks

Comment: Approval Template is only available in 2010.